# QStorageInfo says disk is ready to use while it is not

Tags: macos, qt

`Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.6`.

I have an external drive. In my app, I monitor for it to be connected to PC. 
I use `QStorageInfo` for this providing it with the drive's root path.

On that drive I have a file with a known path to it. I need to check if the file exists once the drive is connected.

The problem is that once I connect the drive, `QStorageInfo` starts to return `true` for both `isValid` and `isReady`, but `QFile::exists` returns `false` while the file is really exists on the drive. It keeps returning `false` for a few seconds. After that seconds it starts returning `true`.

Is it a bug in Qt/MAC or am I missing something?

Qt 5.9.1.

P.S. It works fine on Windows 10.

**Addition #1**. Code Example.

```
QStorageInfo s(storageRootPath);
if (s.isValid() && s.isReady())
{
     auto exists = QFile::exists(pathToFile); // getting false here for a few seconds
}
```

Comment: Share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62039) in Apple CoreFoundation API.